# MySQL join to get a single row using order/priority

Tags: mysql, join

I have a couple tables in MySQL DB

```
EID        Name      
 1        Title A       
 2        Title B       
 3        Title C
```

---

```
LID    EID     Location  Address     Order   
1       1      Office      NY          1
2       1      Home        IL          2
3       2      Office      CA          1
4       3      Home        NJ          2
```

I have the above 2 tables (Employee and Location). I would like to know the location of each Employee with office as a preferred choice and if 'office' does not exist then would need 'Home' location . The order column defined the order/priority of what is needed.

here is the output needed

```
EID  LID       Name        Location   Address
 1    1      Title A       Office     NY
 2    3      Title B       Office     CA
 3    4      Title C       Home       NJ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two posibility to get your result.
**1)If you need Based on Order result then use this query**

```
SELECT e1.EID, l1.LID, e1.Name, l1.Location, l1.Address
FROM Employee e1
JOIN
(SELECT MIN(`Order `) as Minorder, EID, LID, Location, Address, Order
FROM Location l1
GROUP BY EID) l1
ON l1.EID = e1.EID AND l1.Minorder = l1.Order;
```

**2)if you need result Based on EID then use this query**

```
SELECT e1.EID,l1.LID,e1.Name,l1.Location,l1.Address 
FROM Employee e1 JOIN
(SELECT MIN(`EID`)as Mineid,EID,LID,Location,Address,`Order` FROM Location l1 GROUP BY EID)l1
ON l1.Mineid = e1.EID;
```

**Extra Note:-**
Plese donot use mysql inbuilt keyword as Column name or Table name for more information read this link [click here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Answer (score 2):

The first join of the query below just connects the `Employee` and `Location` tables, but note that it results in *all* records from `Location` being joined.  The critical part of the below query is the second `INNER JOIN` to a subquery.  This subquery identifies the minimum (i.e. highest priority) order for each employee ID.  This is then used to discard records from the first join which are not the highest priority.

```
SELECT t1.EID,
       t2.LID,
       t1.Name,
       t2.Location,
       t2.Address
FROM Employee t1
INNER JOIN Location t2
    ON t1.EID = t2.EID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT EID, MIN(`Order`) AS min_order
    FROM Location
    GROUP BY EID
) t3
    ON t2.EID = t3.EID AND
       t2.Order = t3.min_order
```

One other note: *Don't* name your columns `Order`, which is a MySQL keyword.  To get my query to work, I had to put it in backticks, which is inconvenient to say the least, and possibly error prone.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can the expected result by using inner join

```
Select a.eid,b.Lid,a.name,b.location,b.address from Table1 a innner join  (select * from Tableb group by eid) b on
a.eid=b.eid;
```

Comment: In that case I will get 2 records for EID 1, but I need a single record

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code this will help you as i think

```
select E.EID,E.name,ad.LID,ad.LOCATION,ad.ADDRESS,ad.[order]
from @emp E inner join @address ad  on E.EID = ad.EID
            inner join (select EID, min([order]) [order]
                        from @address 
                        group by EID) tt on ad.EID = tt.EIDand ad.[order] = tt.[order]
```